# URL routing issue when data have special symbol

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs

I have developed a ASP.NET MVC application. I have a conroller with the name EmployeeController and it got a method called GetEmployeeByName. GetEmployeeByName() takes a name of type string as parameter.

So When I send a request like this, i get the data back :
someDomain:9999/Employee/GetEmployeeByName/Roger Federer

But if the name contains an '&' (you & me), I get a '400 Bad Request' as response from server.

someDomain:9999/Employee/GetEmployeeByName/you%20&%20me

Even if i encode it dont get a reposne back
someDomain:9999/Employee/GetEmployeeByName/you%20&%20me

**What is the right way to encode such (data with special character) data?**

Answer (score 1):

> What is the right way to encode such (data with special character) data?

The right way is to use a query string parameter and not be putting those things as part of the uri portion. Read the [`following blog post`](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx) from Scott Hansleman. I will only quote hos conclusion:

> After ALL this effort to get crazy stuff in the Request Path, it's
>   worth mentioning that simply keeping the values as a part of the Query
>   String (remember WAY back at the beginning of this post?) is easier,
>   cleaner, more flexible, and more secure.

As you can see in the blog post there are some hacky ways to make it work and circumvent IIS handling but it simply is not something that I would recommend you venturing into. Just put this name in the query string.

Comment: Dimitov: Thank you for the reply. The link was helpful, so I am voting up. But since I decided to use POST the data (so that data is sent in body instead of passing it in URL). I am not marking it as the answer. Thank you for quick reply.